# Translate DDL for tables creation from MySQL to H2

Tags: mysql, syntax, h2

I am trying to set-up some unit/integration tests using an in-memory H2 database, the whole thing wired up with Spring. This is for an existing app that uses MySQL for dev and in production.

Now, I need a DDL SQL script to create my Database structure in H2. I can easily export the DDL statements from MySQL. But I don't know what the differences in syntax are - at least I am pretty sure that things such as `engine=InnoDB` must go.

Are there any other syntax differences I should be aware of ?

Is there a tool that can automatically translate de DDL statements from the MySQL syntax to the H2 syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a quick go at this for a recent project, and this should definitely not be taken as the best or cleanest solution. It should also be noted I used this purely for unit based integration testing. Ideally I'll get this up on github in the next few weeks so people can add to it, but maybe in the meantime it will help. Solution in Java:

```
/**
 * Designed to go through MySQL schema produced from forward engineering tools and normalize slightly to
 * work with H2 for testing. This only works on the SQL constructs themselves and is not able to 
 * detect errors such as constraints with the same name.  
 * 
 * Assumptions
 *      - INDEX is created separately from main SQL body
 *      - Incompatible key words such as order are not used
 *      - Assumes the name of a constraint is not duplicated
 * @author jpgough
 *
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MySqlToH2 {
    public static String convert(String filePath) throws IOException {
        String[] rawSQL = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath))).split("\\n");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(String line : rawSQL) {
            if(line.contains("SET")) {
                continue;
            } else if(line.contains("INDEX")) {
                continue;
            } else if(line.contains("IF NOT EXISTS")) {
                line = line.replaceAll("IF NOT EXISTS", "");
            } else if(line.contains("--")) {
                continue;
            } else if(line.contains("ENGINE")) {
                line = ";";
            }

            line = line.replace("`", "");
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```